# Editing and forwarding email (from different sender) Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, forwarding, mailitem

i'm new in VBA so i need help to understand how can i:

1. taking an email from my inbox, edit the body (deleting the last two rows and the first five rows).
2. Forwarding that modified mail from another mailbox to another one.

Answer (score 1):

> > taking an email from my inbox, edit the body (deleting the last two rows and the first five rows).

First of all, you need to get the Inbox folder in the code. The [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method can help with that. As soon as you retrieved an instance of the `Folder` class you may get an item and edit the message body. The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

> > Forwarding that modified mail from another mailbox to another one.

The [MailItem.Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) method executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a `MailItem` object. For example:

```
Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding() 
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then 
   Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward 
   Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments 
   While myattachments.Count > 0 
     myattachments.Remove 1 
   Wend 
   myItem.Display 
   myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene" 
   myItem.Send 
 Else 
   MsgBox "There is no active inspector." 
 End If 
End Sub
```